# How do I give a user sudo permissions?

Tags: macos, sudo

On my computer I have two accounts: geoff and admin. I want to do `gacutil...`. Doing it in account geoff (where I need it to be done) I get the message:

```
gac directories could not be created, possibly permission issues.
```

When I login as admin this seems to work fine.

So I go back to the geoff account and try `sudo gacutil...` and putting the password for geoff but it tells me that geoff is not in the sudoers file.

So it seems that I either have to get geoff in as a sudoer (how?) or else get my admin account to do the gacutil on geoff's behalf (is this possible?).

Comment: Consider also this answer: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/126400

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Rather than give `geoff` sudo privileges, consider adding the account to the `admin` group so that it inherits the admin group sudoer privileges. This would be the more correct way to do things.

To add `geoff` to the `admin` group you'll need to run the following as the `admin` account:

```
sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a geoff -t user admin
```

You may also want to consider putting `geoff` in the `wheel` group too:

```
sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a geoff -t user wheel
```

The `wheel` group is a BSD-ism, where OS X has its roots. In traditional BSD systems the `wheel` group was used to keep a collection of users who were allowed to become superusers using the `su` command. It's not strictly necessary to be in both `admin` and `wheel` but anyone setup as as "Administrator" on the machine through the UI for adding a user is in both so it can't hurt to replicate that setup.

Comment: This is an interesting suggestion but be aware that this may allow the user to access more then just `sudo`. For instance, adding a user to the `admin` group would allow write access to the `/Applications/` directory, which could lead to security issues or the accidental modifications.

Comment: To reverse this change, change the -a (add) flag to -d (delete):  `sudo dseditgroup -o edit -d geoff -t user admin`

Answer (score 14):

To add a user to sudoers, as admin do `sudo visudo`

Then scroll down to

```
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL) ALL
%admin  ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

place the cursor at the next (empty) line, and press `a` (for append). Then type

```
shortname   ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

where `shortname` is the short name for the user that you are adding to sudoers (there should be `TAB` between the short name and ALL). After that press `ESC` (to exit append mode). Then type `:wq` and then `Enter` to quit visudo, saving the changes.

Comment: what if your shortname has a '.' in it.