# su and sudo without typing passphrase twice

Tags: macos, sudo

On the command line, I find that, if I want to administer something, I must first `login admin` and enter password and then `sudo something` and enter password again. Is there a way to do this in one step, remembering the password for 60 seconds?

This is not a duplicate. I don't want to make my normal user a suoder.

Comment: see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/76088/how-do-i-give-a-user-sudo-permissions and http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/82438/allow-sudo-to-another-user-without-password?rq=1

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. It's best to remove any text that says "this is not a duplicate" and replace it with exact details that will make it abundantly clear to someone _why_ this is distinct from the other similar questions. Putting that in to a question seems to make it a sport to close as duplicate

Answer (score 2):

The passwords used for `login` and `sudo` may be the same, but the authentication mechanism behind is it different. So there is no direct way to avoid having to enter the password twice.

Things you can do to overcome this (but with their own drawbacks):

- Add your current user to `/etc/sudoers`, so you can use `sudo` without having to login as another user. You would still need to enter your password whenever you use `sudo`
- Enable `ssh` and add the public key of current user to the authorized ssh keys of the admin user. This allows you to log in as `admin` with `ssh admin@localhost`, without entering a password

---

For the second option, do the following once you've enabled `ssh` in System Preferences:

- As your normal user, run `ssh-keygen` (and just press enter on all questions)
- Replace ADMIN with the name of the admin user and run

  ```
  ssh ADMIN@localhost "mkdir ~/.ssh; cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys" < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
  ```

  This will be the last time you'll need to enter the password of the admin user to log in
- Run `ssh ADMIN@localhost` to log in as the admin user

Comment: If you are sure there is no easy way, thanks. It just occurred to me, though, that one might perhaps be able to do it with a tmux script; but that would require a safe way to store the password temporarily. (Not sure if environment variables would be safe.)

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe somebody else has better ideas. The solution above is the one I'm using and it's working fine for me.

Answer (score -2):

Once again open root shell, edit `/etc/sudoers` using your favourite text editor, and after entry `%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL` enter `yourusername ALL=(ALL) ALL`, where `yourusername` is your Unix-style user name (*john* or *root* rather than *"John Smith"* or *"System Administrator"*).

Comment: **Never ever** edit `/etc/sudoers` directly with your text editor. If you somehow break the file, you will not be able to `sudo` afterwards, requiring at least a reboot into Single User mode to fix things. From the man page: "The sudoers file should always be edited by the visudo command which locks the file and does
       grammatical checking.  It is imperative that sudoers be free of syntax errors since sudo will
       not run with a syntactically incorrect sudoers file."

Comment: @patrix I have done this. My mac works very good

Comment: I didn't say it doesn't work. It's just risky.

Comment: @patrix If your mac breaks up, it means you have messed up something. My instructions didn't break up anything on my, my brother's and my friend's MacBooks.

Comment: If somebody's "favorite text editor" stores files with DOS line breaks (there are some of those out there) or if somebody makes a typo when entering text in the file, somebody will be stuck.

Comment: @patrix ok, ok, vim or nano

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33826/discussion-between-jakub-kaszycki-and-patrix).

Comment: -1 since "any text editor is a recipe for disaster" and that tools like `visudo` exist to prevent pain that haphazard editing of that file has caused over the years.